# Vagrant up multiple machines using regex

Tags: vagrant, git-bash

In the vagrant manual I [see](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/multi-machine/):

> ... you may have a leader machine as well as a `follower0`, `follower1`, `follower2`, etc. If you want to bring up all the followers but not the leader, you
>   can just do `vagrant up /follower[0-9]/`. If Vagrant sees a machine name
>   within *forward slashes*, it assumes you are using a regular
>   expression.

I tried running the following command on my windows machine (in git bash window) and it failed (my machines name are `node1` and `node2`):

```
$ vagrant.exe up /node[1-2]/
The machine with the name '/node[1-2]/' was not found configured for
this Vagrant environment.
```

I tried playing with the slash for escaping, but it did not work:

```
vagrant.exe up //node[1-2]//
vagrant.exe up \/node[1-2]\/
vagrant.exe up \\node[1-2]\\
```

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [known issue](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6908) and the fix will be included in 1.8.2.

Its already included in core if you want to build vagrant yourself